# AJAX and PHP Data Transfer not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I cannot get the data from my javascript file to my PHP file. I have looked over the look many times and it just doesn't work. Maybe its something simple. Suggestions?? The "yes" response comes back fine from the javascript but the PHP "var_dump($_GET);" comes back with array "(size=0)
  empty"

I'm lost to what's going on.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({  
type: 'POST',  
url: './dev.php',
data: {tradeOf: tradeOf, test: "test"),

success: function(response) {
   alert("yes")
}
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php

var_dump($_GET);

?>
```

Comment: What I am really trying to do is send data via .ajax to a PHP file and have the PHP file use that data to make a request to an API. That's the overall scheme. Am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

JavaScript:

Add a dataType and change the alert so it alerts the response.

```
$.ajax({  
type: 'POST',  
url: './dev.php',
data: {tradeOf: tradeOf, test: "test"),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response) {
   alert(response);
}
})
```

PHP:

Echo back the $_POST via a json_encode.

```
<?php

echo json_encode($_POST);

?>
```

Comment: One more question. How do I then take the JSON data set and pull data out assigning it to a variable in the PHP file?

Comment: In the PHP file you can just do $test = $_POST["test"];
In ajax for the data tag, anything before the colon(:) is the parameter name and after is the data it will hold. So to get the other parameter you would just do: $tradeOf = $_POST["tradeOf"];

Comment: $tradeOf = $_POST["tradeOf"]; I then get response:{"size":".01","price":null,"side":"buy","product_id":"BTC-USD"} $tradeOf = $_POST["tradeOf"];
Code:

$arr = array('size' => '.01', 'price' => $tradeOf, 'side' => 'buy',
 'product_id' => 'BTC-USD');

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data from ajax by POST and using $_GET in php file.
Use var_dump($_POST) in php file.

Comment: I just updated to $_POST so both match still no luck.

Comment: Just check the value of response variable in success of ajax. You are getting any error in console?

Comment: Checked before and just now. No errors in console. I am doing this on a local MAMP PRO server (same directory) but that should not matter.